# Add algorithm2e to ToC with KOMA-Script

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script, algorithm2e

How can I add the list of algorithms from `algorithm2e` to the table of contents of a KOMA-Script class?

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass[oneside,listof=totoc]{scrbook}
\setuptoc{loa}{totoc} %does not work

\usepackage{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\listofalgorithms

\chapter{First}

\begin{algorithm}
\caption{title}
this is an algorithm
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

The use of the global option `dotocloa`, which loads the package `tocbibind` is disliked by KOMA-Script classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the list of algorithms under control of package `tocbasic` use

```
\addtotoclist[float]{loa}
\renewcommand\listofalgorithms{\listoftoc[{\listalgorithmcfname}]{loa}}
```

Example:

```
\documentclass[oneside,listof=totoc]{scrbook}

\usepackage{algorithm2e}
\addtotoclist[float]{loa}% <- added
\renewcommand\listofalgorithms{\listoftoc[{\listalgorithmcfname}]{loa}}% <- added

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listofalgorithms
\chapter{First}
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{title}
this is an algorithm
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

---

With `float` in the optional argument of `\addtotoclist` the list of algorithms has the same owner like LOF and LOT. Therefore `listof=totoc` adds also the LOA to the Table of Contents.

If you choose another owner or omitt the optional argument, you have to add `\setuptoc{loa}{totoc}`:

```
\usepackage{algorithm2e}
\addtotoclist[\jobname]{loa}
\renewcommand\listofalgorithms{\listoftoc[{\listalgorithmcfname}]{loa}}
\setuptoc{loa}{totoc}
```